# SuiteCRM How do I make a custom field named "referred by" that resembles the "assigned to" field?

Tags: sugarcrm, suitecrm

New to SuiteCRM: 
Version 7.6.6
Sugar Version 6.5.23 (Build 1061)

In my Contacts and Accounts modules there is a field called "assigned to", which isn't exactly a dropdown list, but looks like a text field with a blue arrow icon to the right of the field, and a blue X icon to the right of the arrow icon.

When you click the blue arrow, it opens a window that allows you to select from the employee names. I need to use that functionality for a custom "referred by" field.

The "assigned to" field is nowhere to be found in Contacts->Fields, so I have no idea how to edit, clone, or even see where the values are coming from (They are usernames or employee names).

I know how to make a custom field, and I know how to add it to the module layout. But I don't see any data groups that resemble "employee names" or "user names", and that's what I need for the values set for my custom "referred by" field.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sounds to me like you just need to add a related field and set the module to users. You could just rename the label for the "assigned to" to "referred by". This can be done in studio with no code.

Comment: I did a little research, and a little snooping around, and I found a non-programmatic solution in Studio->Accounts->Relationships. Thank you!

Comment: This familiarity with SuiteCRM architecture is so valuable, hard to acquire.  I'm working in SuiteCRM but I have found its documentation woeful.  

Fortunately the SugarCRM documentation is very good indeed, a game-changer.  
e.g.  For this solution I could fill in the gaps confidently using the Admin Guide and the Developer Guide available on 
https://support.sugarcrm.com/Documentation/Unsupported_Versions/Sugar_6.5